# List of Canonical Lists

Tags: discussion, list-questions

I have this idea that just might be a benefit to P.SE, as well as the Stack Exchage Community as a whole:

**A List of Canonical Lists**

For example, when a Canonical list is made, it is not exactly the easiest thing to find, so why not put them all in one place?

We are not looking to make new Canonical Lists. Just organize the old ones.

It will make it more useful to more people, whether they were looking for it or not.

Let me here your thoughts.

Comment: But we don't like canonical lists, they only exists as a last resort when cleaning up not constructive questions... Why encourage them?

Comment: Tag wikis are usually a good place for canonical lists relating to those tags.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Not make new ones, just organize the ones we have.

Comment: @AnnaLear: But they might not be what I'm getting at...

Comment: Jae edit your question to tell us _exactly_ what you had in mind. If this is about existing lists and not creating new ones, it should be clear in the question (even if only for future reference).

Comment: @YannisRizos: Done.

Answer (score -1):

I like the idea of one community wiki question to house all the lists called "The canonical list of lists"  and then linking it in the FAQ under things that shouldn't be asked as "Questions answerable by 'The Canonical list of lists'"

it would be a great way to give people answers to questions without clogging up the site with unwanted questions, and be a lot nicer to link them to a helpful source and closing rather than outright closing.